# How to update Virtual Assistant bot when LUIS endpoint changes

Tags: botframework

I am trying to switch from using the LUIS Authoring Key to using a Subscription Key for both my Assistant and my Skill.  I [created a Subscription Key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/LUIS/get-started-portal-deploy-app#create-the-endpoint-resource) and [assigned it to the LUIS app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/LUIS/get-started-portal-deploy-app#assign-the-resource-key-to-the-luis-app-in-the-luis-portal). What do I need to modify in a Virtual Assistant bot to get it to use the new the new key/endpoint?

I changed the prediction endpoint key to use a Subscription Key so I don't hit [HTTP 403 and HTTP 429 errors](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fcognitive-services%2FLUIS%2Fluis-concept-keys%23key-limit-errors&data=02%7C01%7Cruwill%40microsoft.com%7C36258b98398b487ee70408d6fcb363da%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C636974245219442750&sdata=WtCYeOa8c5sBo2RZ9kEuJ713m%2BgdRLlC%2FMCtJINhojM%3D&reserved=0) and now I need to understand what I need to change in both the Assistant and Skill projects to use this new endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the cognitivemodels.json file to use the subscription key assigned. You need to modify the cognitivemodels.json file in both the Virtual Assistant and Skill (or each skill). Then just re-publish your bot.